# how to stack SKScenes in Xcode using Swift 3

Tags: uiview, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, swift3, skscene

How can I stack SKScenes, and to use push/pop method to switch between the scenes?

Reason I'm asking is because i'm trying to implement an inventory management system to my rogue like game. I want the inventory to show up without transitioning out of the main games scene.

I tried to add an UI subview to the game scene but it didn't work out, because I couldn't add any images(anything that's a SKSpriteNode) to the subview. So, the only option I'm left with is to add another SKScene on top of the main game scene. (Unless someone can enlighten me as how to get SKSpriteNode to work within an UI subview)

Please show me a way to stack SKScenes, in Swift :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Same way you add any other node to a scene,  the only thing is the update and other scene specific functions won't fire.  Also,chances are you do not want to use UIViews, so I would abandon that thought

Comment: You should stick to nodes. Scene added to a scene acts like an ordinary node (like Knight0fDragon pointed, none of scene specific methoda won't fire) and is not meant to be used like that. Wrong approach. There is a way to have multiple scenes stacked using multiple SKViews, but that is not what you really need and can be unperformant becuase in SpriteKit it is originally meant to have one SKView at the time.

Comment: And about adding UIViews to the scene. It is impossible. Scene is presented by the view (SKView). You can add UIView to the view that presents the scene(or to some other UIView). But when you make SKTransition those views wont be removed automatically because they are part of a view and not of a current scene. So again , (IMO) wrong approach.

Comment: @Whirlwind, SKScene stacking is how you handle it via the SpriteKit builder.  You can make multiple SKScenes,  then link them all together with SKReferenceNodes.  The Builder is really powerful and I recommend people to use it to keep design separate from functionality.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I think we are confusing what "stacking" means in OP's example. Having multiple scenes running at the same time  is possible only if using multiple SKViews afaik or if you use Cocos2d. That is how I understood "stacking" in this question. So you stack scenes, and then push and pop them as needed (which, again, it is not possible in SpriteKit).

Comment: @Whirlwind, he just wants to make an inventory overlay, so the "stacking" in his case just means an SKNode that is a child of the SKScene to manage his inventory screen.  This is something that is perfect to do in the SpriteKit builder.  You have 1 sks file for your game,  and 1 sks file for your inventory management.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Stacking in Cocos2d means something else. That is why I said what I said ;) Also, I mentioned that nodes are ideal for this . It is up to OP if he will create those nodes programmatically or using scene editor (and yeah, it can be done like that too, why not). Personally, I use scene editor in some way, to store SKActions for example and reuse them. Cool thing.

Comment: @Whirlwind, oh absolutely,  the new template gives you the action sks file from the get-go now, so hopefully more people start using it.  Once I figured out how powerful the builder is I found that it saved an amazing amount of time.  I can let my artist build the entire scene without ever having to touch code.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon The main reason that I don't use Scene Editor intensively (thus, I don't recommend it often here on SO) is because I think it is not just that powerful at the moment of speaking, like Interface Builder ( imagine Autolayout for SpriteKit :D  ). Other reasons are related to bugs that can be seen now and then as new Xcode versions come out. So, I guess, I am waiting currently because I don't want to get disappointed lol. But that's just me and I can bet this tool will get better and better as time passing.

Comment: @Whirlwind, most of the bugs involving the editor now is user error bugs.  Either somebody is using a non Mac (which apple does not care for those users) or they are not paying attention to how it behaves (which will never change, this is a design choice)  Autolayout on Sprite Kit is not a good idea,  actually it really doesn't make sense unless you are working in a resizeFill scale mode, and besides,  scenes are intended to be larger than a screen (infinitely).  How do you plan on designing a full level like in Super Mario Bros with Autolayout.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Well for tiled based games it doesn't make sense. But I think it would be cool for menu scenes, or game over scenes. You know, I hate to position sprites programmatically :) Instead of writing boring positioning code, you define constraints visually and have your menu elements where you want. Like in UIKit application.

Comment: @Whirlwind, you do not position sprites programmatically in the editor lol Plus the editor has snapping functionality. Unless you are making games in a resizeFill scale mode, you are only be developing for 1 size. Until Apple introduces a method in Sprite Kit itself to anchor nodes at certain borders of a scene, we will not see any kind of layouts.  Actually, an SKConstraintScene would be a nice tool to create, and with userData, would be possible to implement in the Builder

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I said I don't use editor for that, just for SKActions. So I am not referring in this case to Scene editor ;), means I do position sprites programmatically.

Comment: @Whirlwind, you said you do not use the scene builder because it doesn't have Autolayout (among other tiny reasons), and that you hate position programattically. Just letting you know that it could be achieved with the current editor once an SKConstraintScene class is created to handle it thanks to being able to add userData

Comment: @Knight0fDragon No, I said I don't use scene builder because I think it is not powerful like IB. I haven't said I don't use it because it doesn't have Autolayout, but rather said that IMO, it would be nice to have something like that in SpriteKit. Not exact cloned Autolayout feature of course, but something adjusted for SpriteKit. And it seems that we are about to go into off topic lol.

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs! I have found a solution to my problem. I ended up using multiple UIViewControllers. one for the main game scene, one for the Inventory scene, and use segue to link them. So when I click on the inventory icon in the game scene the inventory scene pops up and overlays the game scene. It also puts the games scene on pause. When I dismiss the Inventory scene, the game returns to the game scene and the gameplay resumes. Not sure if it's a good way for doing it, but it gets the job done.